# uibutton to push nib

Tags: iphone

is there any way i can make a uibutton push a nib in my nav controller?

Comment: "push a nib?" What do you mean by that?

Comment: @Nicholas - I'll tell you when you're older. ;-)

Comment: Man, I really got myself into that one didn't I? :-)  I hope this doesn't start a suggestive Stack Overflow trolling category...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Question is not that clear, My interpretation of it is that you want to push a new controller onto the nav stack that has been initialised by a nib..

```
myViewC= [[[MyViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MyViewController" bundle:nil];

[navigationController pushViewController:myViewC animated:YES];
```